# Number theory problem for undergraduates

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Show that there cannot exist two distinct positive integers $m $ and $n$ such that both ${a^m+b^m=c^m}$  and ${ a^n+b^n=c^n}$  hold.

This problem was given for undergraduate entrance exam, so any help without higher math.

Comment: Counterexample: $a=b=c=0$, choose any $m$ and $n$ you want.

Comment: You should describe the assumptions on $\{a,b,c\}$.  For example, if $a=-b, c=0$ there are infinitely many exponents that work.

Comment: If you assume $a,b,c$ are also positive integers, then it is trivial. Take $n>m$. Then $c^n=(a^m+b^m)c^{n-m}>a^ma^{n-m}+b^mb^{n-m}=a^n+b^n$

Comment: I think there's a word "positive " mentioned.

Comment: @Geo That's irrelevant because the word "positive" only applies to integers $m$ and $n$.  You haven't said anything about $a,b,c$.

Comment: WLOG out generality assume that $m < n$. Then you only have to prove it for $m=1$ and $n=2$. The rest is covered by Fermat's Last Theorem for the case $n \ge 3$.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG out generality assume that $m < n$. Then you only have to prove it for $m=1$ and $n=2$. The rest is covered by Fermat's Last Theorem for the case $n \ge 3$ which guarantees there is no such solution of this form.

So, for the sake of contradiction, assume that $$a + b = c$$ and $$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$

Now, $$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$
$$\implies a^2 + b^2 = (a+b)^2$$
$$\implies 2ab = 0$$

Now, we know that either $a=0$ or $b=0$.